# Installing xdebug on OS X Lion 10.7.6

Tags: php, xcode, xdebug

So I have xdebug installed but im guessing its the wrong version as I downloaded a precompiled version and it doesn't work so I decided to make my own. I followed the instructions on the xdebug site and when it comes to running phpize I get the following error:

```
Cannot find config.m4. 
Make sure that you run './phpize' in the top level source directory of the module
```

When I run phpize in the directory /usr/bin I get the same error.

When I try to see what version of phpize I am running I get the following error:

```
grep: /usr/include/php/main/php.h: No such file or directory
grep: /usr/include/php/Zend/zend_modules.h: No such file or directory
grep: /usr/include/php/Zend/zend_extensions.h: No such file or directory
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:        
Zend Module Api No:     
Zend Extension Api No:
```

Also another thing which is stopping me in my tracks is that I have no gcc compiler I have unisntalled and reinstalled xcode twice now with no prevail...

Comment: Lion isn't up to version 10.7.6 yet, it's only at 10.7.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XDebug was working all along I hadnt turned html_errors on in my php.ini file and I hadn't changed the application_env to development in my index.php file as I am using the zend Framework! Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

You should run phpize inside directory with xdebug source code. Its not related to xcode. Then you compile it with make scripts and copy result module to php extensions folder. Are you sure that you got correct source from git?

Comment: If I do that I get this error:

    grep: /usr/include/php/main/php.h: No such file or directory
    grep: /usr/include/php/Zend/zend_modules.h: No such file or directory
    grep: /usr/include/php/Zend/zend_extensions.h: No such file or directory
    Configuring for:
    PHP Api Version:        
    Zend Module Api No:     
    Zend Extension Api No:  
    Cannot find autoconf. Please check your autoconf installation and the
    $PHP_AUTOCONF environment variable. Then, rerun this script.

Comment: does sudo help? you might have a conflict of having two php versions, since mac has one preinstalled, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5789504/two-versions-of-php-on-mac-os-snow-leopard-installing-xdebug-using-pecl

Comment: if i use php -i I get 5.3.8 which is what i also get through my info.php file. I guess this means I could have the same version installed twice? I have no clue how to fix this at all... Oh and sudo doesn't help at all..