# Warning: date_default_timezone_get():

Tags: symfony

I have researched all the answers I can find for this and have had no luck getting it to work.

I am getting the following error when I try to run symfony.

> Warning: date_default_timezone_get(): It is not safe to rely on the
>   system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the
>   date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In
>   case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this
>   warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We
>   selected the timezone 'UTC' for now, but please set date.timezone to
>   select your timezone. in /symfony_project/app/cache/dev/classes.php
>   line 5229

I have checked the following :

> php --ini
>
> Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc Loaded Configuration File:
>   /etc/php.ini

I have changed the ini file to date.timezone = "Europe/Dublin"

restarted apache 
Cleared the cli cache
cleared the browser cache

Ran phpinfo and confirmed the

loaded config file is etc/php.ini
Additional .ini files parsed    (none)
date.timezone = "Europe/Dublin"
I also ran echo date_default_timezone_get() in the browser and I get Europe/Dublin

I am running PHP v 5.4.24 (for what its worth)

I ran echo date_default_timezone_get() inside 
which returns UTC ... so it looks like symfony is not reading the php.ini file properly.

Not sure what else I can do.

Comment: Do you have the error when running Symfony from command-line or server (in other words, viewing it in your browser)? And do you see the timezone when viewing phpinfo?

Comment: Take a look this post -> http://stackoverflow.com/a/20743237/453348

Comment: Im getting the error in the browse when loading localhost:8000

Comment: from php.ini date.timezone = Europe/Dublin

Comment: Ive also looked at that post ttony

Comment: ok i've run phpinfo() from inside symphony and it is reading a totaly different php.ini because the Default timezone UTC,  date.timezone = no value and Configuration File (php.ini) Path /etc
Loaded Configuration File (none)

Comment: So you may have not edited the right php.ini file.

Comment: Ive edited the php.ini file that is loaded but for some reason symfony is not reading form that ini file

Comment: Are you using the server included in Symfony2? I think of this because you use `localhost:8000`, is it the default server from your computer?

Comment: I didnt know symfony had a built in server. (Where can i find that)  Im using the built in apache server on my mac which run os x mavericks.

Comment: Sorry you meant php app/console server:run

Comment: ive run the php app/check.php and i get                              OK       date.timezone setting must be set
OK       Configured default timezone "Europe/Dublin" must be supported by your installation of PHP

Comment: When running `php app/check.php` you're using the CLI version of PHP, which may use a different .ini file than the one used by Apache.

Comment: Thanks for the help ... I ended up deleting the project that would'nt work and created a fresh project and it works.

Answer (score -1):

1. find your php.ini file path

   ```
   php -i | grep php.ini
   ```
2. edit **php.ini** date_timezone set it is your timezone

   ```
   time_zone = "Asia/Shanghai"
   ```
3. restart your **nginx** and **php-fpm**