# Acme Bundle Installation error: Warning it is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings

Tags: symfony

I am trying to install Symfony2 on my localhost (MAMP), I followed the installation instruction available on the official Symfony site.

First i installed the composer and moved it to a specific directory.

```
$ curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php 
$ sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

I then executed the installation command:

```
composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition *my-project-path-in-MAMP-htdocs*/ "2.5.*"
```

During Installation process I am prompted with a question if I want to instal Acme bundle I type 'y' to confirm that I do want to instal this Bundle....

But during the installation of that Bundle I get this Error message:

`Warning: date_default_timezone_get(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'Europe/London' for 'BST/1.0/DST' instead in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Symfony/project1/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php line 233`

Can anyone help me or suggest a solution...?

Comment: possible duplicate of [date\_default\_timezone\_get(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12543236/date-default-timezone-get-it-is-not-safe-to-rely-on-the-systems-timezone-set)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the parameter `date.timezone` in your php.ini for every valid [timezone](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php) and after that do not forget to restart Apache, try if this solve your issue

**Procedure**

I'm not use LAMP environment since I work with Linux but things should be the same as Mac is *nix. Anyway, you should find where `php.ini` file is under your directory structure (again I not use MacOS so I can't help here) and open it with any text editor or console text editor (personally I prefer this one) and find for that string `date.timezone` when you found it just uncomment that line by removing the `;` symbol at front of the string and add a valid timezone lets said for example `Europe/Amsterdam` then you should have something like:

```
date.timezone = Europe/Amsterdam
```

That's all, restart your LAMP environment if you use any stack application or just restart Apache service, that will be all

Comment: Thank you for your answer could you possibly explain/show how this is done.?

Comment: @ZiomekZiomski take a look to my edition seconds ago

Comment: can I set it as Europe/London does this make any difference...?

Comment: and Do i have to remove the ; whihc is in front of date.timezone..?

Comment: @ZiomekZiomski you can set whatever you want just take care around `DateTime` objects and dates format and so on

Comment: Yes, you need to remove the `;` symbol, if you leave it as it then you are telling that is not enabled (how should be by default) if you remove then after restart your webserver it's enabled

Comment: Yep your answer is perfect and very clear instructions given..!!! Also as I only started on stack i am very poor with point would also appreciate vote up :P