# php --version show a different php version than I expected

Tags: php

This is a snippet from my .bash_profile

```
export MAMP_PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/bin/php
export PATH="$MAMP_PATH:$PATH"
```

but when i run

```
$ php --version
```

I get this output:

```
PHP 5.3.15 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Jul 31 2012 14:49:18) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies
```

Why!?

Comment: By any chance, do you have multiple PHP installations?

Comment: MAMP has ability to use several versions. What is the Preference setting?

Comment: This probably belongs at [http://serverfault.com/](http://serverfault.com/)

Comment: The CLI version is most likely pointing at the OS bundled version of PHP. Take a look at this thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4262006/how-to-use-mamps-version-of-php-instead-of-the-default-on-osx

Answer (score 1):

Find out which `php` is being called by running the command `which php`.

The solution will probably be to change `MAMP_PATH` to this:

`export MAMP_PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/bin`

(In the path you specify a directory, not a binary)