# MAMP vs system PHP .. completely separate?

Tags: php, macos

How does the PHP that MAMP uses run differently from the PHP installed on my Mac?

For example, if if place an bare "phpinfo()" file and access it through my browser into MAMP/htdocs .. the information supplied is my MAMP PHP setup, correct?

But if I terminal into that same folder and "php -i" from command line, I will get the details of my Mac's "system" PHP, correct?

So does that mean that extensions must be separately installed into both setups?  Do they need to be managed as 2 completely separate entities?  Any PEAR packages installed via command line will not be available to MAMP?  If I want to keep the two synchronous I must "double" everything?

Answer (score 1):

All user-installed versions of PHP are installed into a separate folder, keeping the original install of PHP intact. MAMP is only set up to use its version of PHP in the browser.

You can change this behavior by updating your PATH to use MAMP's version, if you don't care about the stock PHP version (which is fairly old). You can do that by adding the following line to your `~/.bash_profile` (don't forget to double-check the exact path, so you get it right):

```
export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5/bin/:$PATH
```

This will make all references to PHP use MAMP's version.

If you need to use the stock version of PHP for whatever reason and don't want to do the above, then you can create an alias. More details for creating command line aliases can be found in [this related SO post.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4262717/570040)

Comment: Thank you. I have created a "phpm" alias to my MAMP php5.4.10 and things look good.  Do I need to keep anything in mind in the future with regard to PEAR or extensions or anything, or is this fairly "set and forget"?

Comment: As long as you set it in your `~/.bash_profile` file, and use your alias for all CLI commands, it should be pretty much "set and forget".