# How to solve Laravel requires php mcrypt extension?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, mcrypt

I searched the net, I followed the instructions to solve this problem but I could not solve it,
when I want to use Laravel php artisian it gives errors like this:

```
Laravel requires php Mcrypt extenstion.
```

Note: I am using MAMP in Mac

please give example and solution for mac with MAMP.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Laravel requires the Mcrypt PHP extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16830405/laravel-requires-the-mcrypt-php-extension)

Comment: Dear the answers that were given did not solved my problem so I asked this question I have tried all those steps.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue on Ubuntu 12.04.  What version of PHP are you running and does Mcrypt show up as active when you run:

```
<?php
phpinfo()?
?>
```

Comment: In my MAMP in phpinfo it shows Mcrypt enabled but when I write PHP artisan in terminal it gives the error: Laravel requires the PHP Mcrypt extenstion

Comment: Ahhh... I had the same issue.  What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: My MAMP php version is:  5.4.10
please help me I am new with it.

Comment: This should answer your question:   [Check Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16830405/laravel-requires-the-mcrypt-php-extension)

Answer (score 0):

It's quite possible that your command-line PHP isn't the same that MAMP is using, but rather the one that came with OSX. To find out, you can open your terminal and type `php -i | grep php.ini`, which will show you what ini file you're using.

If this is the case, which seems likely, you can follow the steps of older SO posts [such as this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4262006/how-to-use-mamps-version-of-php-instead-of-the-default-on-osx) to create a symlink or overwrite the default PHP.

Alternatively, you can upgrade your system's PHP using Homebrew, for instance. I'm running 5.5.8 on my Macs, and it's working great. Do note that I do not necessarily recommend this, though, as configuring MAMP to use the new version isn't a fun experience. Also note that if you do this, you'll have to install both PHP and Mcrypt through Homebrew.