# the requested linked library openssl has the wrong version installed

Tags: php, openssl, composer-php, mamp

I recently ran composer update and this is the error I get:

> - namshi/jose 5.0.2 requires lib-openssl * -> the requested linked library openssl has the wrong version installed or is missing from
>     your system, make sure to have the extension providing it

.

I am using MAMP. How may I get this fixed ?
I tried upgrading the openssl version on my mac as some stack overflow answers said , but no luck

```
which openssl
```

shows

```
/usr/local/bin/openssl


openssl version
```

shows

```
OpenSSL 1.0.2h  3 May 2016
```

Comment: Which version of PHP are you running?

Comment: phpinfo says 5.6.10

Comment: Well it looks like you've got the right versions, although you now should check to make sure PHP has the OpenSSL module/extension installed so it can interface with it.

Comment: when I go to php info, the version is different.
under the CURL section, this is one of the rows:
SSL Version OpenSSL/0.9.8zd

Comment: Ah okay, then it sounds like your mamp isn't linked up to the newer version. In that case you'll probably want to look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4262006/how-to-use-mamps-version-of-php-instead-of-the-default-on-osx. or you still need to install something for OpenSSL...

Comment: This question dealt with a similar problem as yours, although they seemed to have an older version of PHP as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37322446/laravel-composer-install-could-not-solve-installable-package-for-tymon-jwt-auth

Comment: phpmamp --help
says command not found after alias phpmamp='/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.6.10/bin/php'

Comment: It's actually `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.(your version)/bin/php`... Look in `/Applications/MAMP/bin/...`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113090/discussion-between-harvey-slash-and-lll).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final conclusion was to UNINSTALL MAMP , and then install apache,mysql and php using brew (it took me less than 5 minutes to set up all three).
Then installation of 3rd party packages(including openssl) was a breeze.

Overall it took me 10 minutes, and I would say its worth it.