# OS Mountain LION PHP Environment Variable

Tags: php, macos, path, env

I have freshly installed Mac OS 10.8 Mountain Lion and I have noticed that the PHP version the system is using is not the one associated to MAMP.

I used to modify my PATH variable to point my OS to use a different BIN folder for PHP but I just cant find where to modify the PATH variable in 10.8 anymore.

I created a .profile and look into the `.bash_profile` file as well but the OS keeps on using

```
/usr/bin/php
```

as the default PHP installation instead of

```
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.14/bin
```

Where can I find the system PATH variable setting?

Comment: Try the `which` command: `which php` - maybe Mac OSX has it, I don't know.

Comment: which php tells me what instance of PHP is the OS using but wont allow me to change it.

Comment: Please see first: [How to run a PHP script from the command line with MAMP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/954910/367456) - Take care you have the path to the PHP binary in the MAMP folder *before* the systems binary path. `echo $PATH` should output your current path variable. If you can not solve it your own already, add that output to your question.

Comment: I would assume you just either did not execute `.bash_profile` so far to update the path (don't call it directly, just open a new shell and try in there) or you placed it at the wrong end (behind instead before the systems `$PATH`)

Comment: MY path to the PHP binary folder doesnt point to MAMP-PRO. This exactly what I want to do, to change the PATH form the default OS php installation to the MAMP bin path. If I do a "which php" I get "/usr/bin/php"

Comment: Make your `$PATH` point to it first. What does `echo $PATH` give you so far?

Comment: /Users/jfernandez/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/bin:/Users/jfernandez/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@global/bin:/Users/jfernandez/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/bin:/Users/jfernandez/.rvm/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin

Answer (score 0):

For me I can edit my ~/.profile file in mountain lion. I'm not sure where the original PHP path is located but you could try adding 
`export PATH="$PATH:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.14/bin"` 
to your .profile file. Make sure to restart your terminal before running which php.