# How to change Terminal default php.ini

Tags: php, terminal, mamp

I'm Installing Laravel, and it requires `mcrypt` extension to be activated. I want to know how to change the *php.ini* that Terminal uses to the one in my Apache (MAMP).

How can I do that?

Comment: Read [this post](http://www.glenscott.co.uk/blog/2011/08/29/install-mcrypt-php-extension-on-mac-os-x-lion/). You can google it :-)

Comment: @shin
Ok that's was useful , but i prefer changing the php.ini that terminal deals with , that will be better for me .

Comment: php.ini in Mac is /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.2.17/conf/php.ini
or  
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/conf/php.ini

Comment: @shin
I want to change it to this dir.
/applications/mamp/bin/php/php5.4.10/conf/php.ini
this is my mamp php.ini file

Comment: I'm going to try the article you've put and i'll post the results

Comment: The article you've posted envolves downloading and installing xCode and that's require a lot of time with my internet connection
I just want to install that mcrypt lib for laravel :(

Comment: Surely you want to use a different PHP binary, not a different PHP ini file?  Use "which php" on your terminal to find out where PHP is right now.

Comment: @PhillSparks
Yep ! I was looking for that !
How can i change that dir to my apache php bin ??

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/11035955/1269513 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/4262717/1269513

Comment: @PhillSparks
YOU MADE MY DAY !!
Thanks very much sir !!
Laravel 4 Finally is working :)